# how to expect 'render template' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a view template "show.html.haml", something like

```
- if current_user.admin?
  balabala
```

It will get "undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass" while GET #show. I fixed it with " - if !current_user.nil? && current_user.admin?". And I want to add a test case with RSpec.

```
describe "before login user - " do

  it "render the show template" do
    book = FactoryGirl.create(:book)
    get :show, id: book.id

    expect(response).to render_template("show")
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

While run "bin/rake spec", it always get success no matter if I add the condition "!current_user.nil?". How can I write the expect clause while I want to check if rendering 'show' view is sucess?

Answer (score 3):

As you are trying to test content of view from [`controller spec`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#controller-specs) , you can not do that directly.

You can use [`render_views`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/render-views) declaration to do that but it is **not recommended** rather you should go for either [`request spec`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#request-specs) or [`feature spec`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#feature-specs) to test the complete request - response cycle.

Setting up `render_views` globally:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.render_views
end
```

Spec:

```
describe "before login user - " do
  it "render the show template" do
    book = FactoryGirl.create(:book)
    get :show, id: book.id
    expect(response).to render_template("show")
    expect(response.body).to match /balabala/
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

By default views do not get rendered in controller specs. You need to explicitly enable it by writing `render_views` (in your `describe` block). See the reference: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/controller-specs/render-views

Answer (score 0):

You need to "sign in" in your spec. Don't change your code just to make the test passed. Check rendering is successful or not is simple, just check the response status:

```
expect(response.status).to eq 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `type: :view` like so.

```
describe "before login user - ", type: :view do
  it "render the show template" do
    book = FactoryGirl.create(:book)
    get :show, id: book.id

    expect(response).to render_template("show")
    expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```